# How to configure mono to use more than 4G memory?

Tags: f#, mono

I want to run an .NET executable that needs more than 4G RAM on OSX 10.9. I had Xamarin Studio installed but AFAIKT Xamarin doesn't come with a 64-bit mono build, so I decided to make a custom 64-bit mono with "with-large-heap=yes" configuration, and install it in a different location.

```
git clone https://github.com/mono/mono
cd mono
./configure --prefix=<my-local-dir> --enable-nls=no --with-large-heap=yes
make
make install
```

(I also built a 64-bit F# and installed in my-local-dir, following "Option 3" in [this page](http://fsharp.org/use/mac/).)

However, when I use the 64-bit mono to run the executable (an F# program built with the canonical "fsharpc" in Xamarin), it still crashes with System.OuOtfMemory exception. I tried this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<my-local-dir>/bin
MONO_GC_PARAMS=max-heap-size=5g <my-local-dir>/bin/mono <my-executable>
```

And it gives a warning

```
Warning: In environment variable `MONO_GC_PARAMS': `max-heap-size` must be an integer.
```

(this error message is a bit misleading, I think it really means 5g is too large and not supported, because it doesn't complain if I put a "3g" there). And the program still crash with the same exception at the point when it exceeds the memory.

Did I miss any thing important? How do I configure mono to have more than 4G heap size?

Comment: Actually, 5g (which is evaluated as the number 5,368,709,120) IS not an integer (assuming 32-bit long integers), as it is too large. Amusingly, you're hitting the 32-bit limit TWICE :)

Comment: yeah you are definitely right! Actually, 5g not being recognized as "integer" suggests the mono binary I ended up building was still a 32-bit binary. I just learned a "new" trick that "mono -V" will print out the architecture, where I checked it was still x86 instead of amd64. 

After fixing the problematic environment variable the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still running the 32 bit version of mono (check your PATH env var). This also explains the parsing of 5g for max-heap-size (it will work correctly with 64 bit mono).
The default as with your configure command above is to install in /usr/local/bin, so just run your programs with /usr/local/bin/mono program.exe.

Comment: thanks! yeah that's exactly the reason. I searched "i386" from config.status and I found my $CC was somehow defined as "cc -arch i386", which explained why I ended up building a 32-bit mono. After fixing the environment variables I got this working.